# How can I enforce an error when a function doesn't have any return in GCC?

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors, compilation

Is it possible to enforce an error (to break the build) when a function definition has no return in its body?

Consider this function:

```
int sum(int a, int b) {
  int c = a + b;
  // And here should be return
};
```

When I compile with `g++ -Wall`, I get:

> no `return` statement in function returning non-void [`-Wreturn-type`]

But I want this to be a hard error rather than a warning.

I'm currently using GCC 4.9.2, but if there's a solution for different version of GCC that would be helpful to know, too.

Comment: You can turn warnings into errors with `-Werror`

Comment: Ok, but I want treat this one as error, another warning may be ignored.

Comment: `-Werror=return-type `

Answer (score 26, accepted):

GCC has the option [`-Werror`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Werror) to turn all warnings into errors.

If you want to upgrade only a specific warning, you can use `-Werror=X`, where `X` is the warning type, without the `-W` prefix.  In your particular case, that would be `-Werror=return-type`.

Note that this will only report a missing `return` in a function that returns a value.  If you want to enforce that `return;` must be explicitly written in a function returning `void`, you may be out of luck.